# Sharepoint 2013: AD users not found on people/user picker, but they shows up only in Central Admin site

Tags: 2013, active-directory, people-picker, synchronisation

I'm having problem with my SharePoint 2013 people picker. It doesn't shows any AD users at all.

But strangely, when I pick/search people in its Central Administration site, all my AD users are shown.

Both of the site are on the same server and of course were installed as a same package of sharepoint installation.

Did I missed something? I have done previously installation of SP2010, but never came across this problem. Any log files or event log to look at?

Thank you so much for your help... :)

One more thing, I'm new to sharepoint :)

Comment: Having the same issues/problems over here. Actually I am wondering what you mean with the PP working in CA. For me in CA adding a site collection administrator from another domain is possible but that way you are not using the PeoplePicker. Adding a user from another domain to my farm admin group is not possible. I had to configure the PeoplePicker (allthough I do have 2-way trusts with all other domains) by setting an encryption password and setting the peoplepicker-searchadforests attribute to make it work So actually you have to configure the PP like you have a ONE-way trust to make it work

Comment: you can try to "iis reset" I encountered the same problem as you, with the method by ali, and restart the iis.
The problem is resolved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: ad import]

> Active Directory Import is similar to the Profile import mechanism we
>   had back in SharePoint Server 2007. It's an awful lot easier and
>   quicker to configure than "SharePoint Profile Synchronisation", AKA
>   "User Profile Synchronisation Service" (in services on server) AKA
>   ForeFront Identity Manager (FIM) for SharePoint Server 2010.
>
> Enabling AD Import mode can be achieved via SPCA following UPA
>   creation within "Configure Synchronization Settings". You can happily
>   change the setting in the UI (although I have had occasional issues
>   with the relevant JavaScript not firing):

using powershell

```
$upa=Get-SPServiceApplication -Name "UserProfileServiceAppName" 

$upa.NoILMUsed=$true 

$upa.Update()
```

http://www.benjaminathawes.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=c4ef5a3d%2D6f2b%2D40cf%2Da53d%2D04e9f3beedd4&ID=42&Web=b5c13492%2D56d6%2D4868%2D90bf%2Da96d72070f07

**EDIT**

**To select SharePoint Active Directory Import**

> 1. Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is a member of the Farm Administrators group.
>
>    2. On the SharePoint Central Administration website, in the Application Management section, click Manage service applications.
>    3. On the Manage Service Applications page, click the User Profile service application name.
>    4. On the Manage Profile Service page, in the Synchronization section, click Configure Synchronization Settings.
>    5. On the Configure Synchronization Settings page, in the Synchronization Options section, select the Use SharePoint Active
>         Directory Import option, and then click OK.

the above i presume is what you have already done?

**To create a connection to a directory service for import**

> 1. Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is a member of the Farm Administrators group.
> 2. On the SharePoint Central Administration website, in the Application Management section, click Manage service applications.
> 3. On the Manage Service Applications page, click the User Profile service application name.
> 4. On the Manage Profile Service page, in the Synchronization section, click Configure Synchronization Connections.
> 5. On the Synchronizations Connections page, click Create New Connection.
> 6. On the Add new synchronization connection page, type the synchronization connection name in the Connection Name box.
> 7. From the Type list, select Active Directory Import.
> 8. Fill in the Connection Settings section by using the following steps:
>
>    1. In the Fully Qualified Domain Name box, type the Fully Qualified Domain Name of the domain.
>    2. In the Authentication Provider Type box, select the type of authentication provider.
>    3. If you select Forms Authentication or Trusted Claims Provider Authentication, select an authentication provider from the
>         Authentication Provider Instance box.    The Authentication Provider
>         Instance box lists only the authentication providers that are
>         currently used by a Web application.
>    4. In the Account name box, type the synchronization account in the form \. The synchronization account must have
>         Replicate Directory permissions or higher on the root OU of Active
>         Directory.
>    5. In the Password box, type the password for the synchronization account.
>    6. In the Confirm password box, type the password for the synchronization account again.
>    7. In the Port box, type the connection port.
>    8. If a Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) connection is required to connect to the directory service, select Use SSL-secured connection.
>
>    9.If you want to filter the objects to be imported from the directory service, in the Filter in LDAP syntax for Active Directory Import box,
>      type a standard LDAP query expression to define the filter.
> 9. In the Containers section, click Populate Containers, and then select the containers from the directory service that you want to
>      synchronize. All OUs selected will be synchronized with their child
>      OUs. There is currently no utility to allow a parent OU to be selected
>      with any of its child OUs excluded from synchronization.
> 10. Click OK.   The newly created connection is listed on the Synchronization Connections page.

**To map user profile properties**

> 1. Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is a member of the Farm Administrators group.
> 2. On the SharePoint Central Administration website, in the Application Management section, click Manage service applications.
> 3. On the Manage Service Applications page, click the User Profile service application name.
> 4. On the Manage Profile Service page, in the People section, click Manage User Properties.
> 5. On the Manage User Properties page, right-click the name of the property that you want to map to a directory service attribute, and
>      then click Edit.
> 6. To remove an existing mapping, in the Property Mapping for Synchronization section, select the mapping that you want to remove,
>      and then click Remove.
> 7. To add a new mapping, do the following:
>
>    1. In the Add New Mapping section, in the Source Data Connection list, select the data connection that represents the directory service
>         to which you want to map the user profile property.
>    2. In the Attribute box, type the name of the directory service attribute to which you want to map the property.
>    3. Click Add.
> 8. Click OK.
> 9. Repeat steps 5 through 8 to map additional properties.

**To start profile synchronization**

> 1. Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is a member of the Farm Administrators group.
> 2. On the SharePoint Central Administration website, in the Application Management section, click Manage service applications.
> 3. On the Manage Service Applications page, click the User Profile service application name.
> 4. On the Manage Profile Service page, in the Synchronization section, click Start Profile Synchronization.
> 5. On the Start Profile Synchronization page, select Start Full Synchronization if this is the first time that you are synchronizing
>      or if you have added or modified any synchronization connections since
>      the last time that you synchronized. Select Start Incremental
>      Synchronization to synchronize only information that has changed since
>      the last time that you synchronized.
> 6. Click OK.   The Manage Profile Service page is displayed, showing the profile synchronization status in the right pane.

make sure you follow all the steps above!

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj219646.aspx

Comment: I have tried the above suggestion by changing the option to use active directory import. But still, it doesn't fix.

Here's the pic from my CA. It works correctly as I mentioned in my question:
http://s21.postimg.org/859gotztz/sp2013_from_CA.jpg

But in my other non-CA site, it doesn't work:
http://s21.postimg.org/yez4ldb53/sp2013_fromsite.jpg

Comment: just ammended my answer, check out the edit part and follow all the steps to sync AD with your site ;)

Comment: thank you for the information... I've done all the steps above. But still the AD users don't show up for the picker on the SP site. They are only shows on any picker on CA site. It suppose to be the same right? If we can view the AD users on CA site, it should be viewable also on the other SP site? I've check the job history after executing the sync, it says "Succeeded", but it took only 00.00 for the duration. It looks like doing nothing.

Comment: I've checked that the account used for AD import should have a "replicate directory changes" permission. I have added it, and the sync process took more time than previously (around 5 minutes). But then, still no effect. The AD users still not showing on the site.

how does really the user picker works? Should it have the same technique inside it for both CA and site? Are there differences between them? 

If no differences at all, then why only the CA can show all AD user? what happen to the other sp site?

Comment: In my case. I've done every step, except the last one. The status didn't change. It was still Idle. Is there anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to UP Sync. Make sure your web app accounts have permissions to make AD lookups (add them to Domain Users) as the People Picker is run under this security context.