# User Import problems

Tags: user, import, ad

I have a problem that I can't resolve with many searches or impossible to understand.

I am using the AD import with my SharePoint install 2013 sever.

My problem is  :

The AD import is ok , I can find all users of my AD domain by using the "search users" in "manage user profile" via central administration.

My problem is, I just want to make users search and i can't, everywhere i go in SharePoint right management, I cant add these imported users, cause SharePoint can't see nothing.

[image]
Without this, I can't select rights, for administration sites, or share sites, applications, or web applications.

Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: IISReset is ok, but no more change ... allways the user/group searsh see "all user", but no one imported user...

I have read all posts on your link, and that i already make..

The word "people picker" seem to be the problem...

can i try a way with power shell for exemple as ?:

"stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "forest:habaneros.com;forest:contoso.com,contoso\ReadAccount,P@ssw0rd" -url hppt://mycentr@l-admInlink:port"
I think that can be a solution, but in my case, my domain is sauros.local, and i have a SP_UPS acount with replicating rights

thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 0):

After configuration do an IISRESET. If problem still persist then follow below thread

[Sharepoint 2013: AD users not found on people/user picker, but they shows up only in Central Admin site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/63214/sharepoint-2013-ad-users-not-found-on-people-user-picker-but-they-shows-up-onl)